# ReactJS recieving form errors from server

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

Below is my signup function in React. How can I render the errors it recieves from backend ? I tried to put a this.setResponse into the catch part ... that didn't work. I understand that componentWillReceiveProps should handle updates but this is an update from a Service (also below) not from a parent component.

If I print the err I can see a dictionary with errors, but I don't see how to pass them to the form or to the fields for rendering.

```
signup(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    ...
      Auth.signup(dict)
        .catch(function(err) {
            alert("There's an error signing up");
            console.log(err.response);
      });
},
```

The Auth service is defined like this:

```
signup(dict) {
    console.log(dict);
    return this.handleAuth(when(request({
        url: UserConstants.SIGNUP_URL,
        method: 'POST',
        type: 'json',
        data: dict
    })));
}
```

And I hoped to send errors to the fields with the following:

```
<UserNameField
    ref="username"
    responseErrors={this.responseErrors}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that `UserNameField` is in the same component as the auth callback you can just set the state which will trigger a re-render and pass the values through `UserNameField` as props.

```
signup(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    ...
      Auth.signup(dict)
        .catch((err) => {
            alert("There's an error signing up");
            console.log(err.response);
            this.setState({error: err});
      });
},

<UserNameField
    ref="username"
    responseErrors={this.responseErrors}
    error={this.state.error}
/>
```

This is the same as `.bind(this)`.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, didn't work. Auth.signup is imported to the Form component from services, that is probably why "this" is undefined in the catch function ...  But I look if reshufling it in to the Form component would make sense.

Comment: @Stefan Use es6 arrow function. this should be defined now. Updated answer.

Comment: Now it says: "Parsing error: Property assignements valid only in destructuring patterns". Don't know what tath means, just learning about arrow function, but I do have stage-0 installed and working, also babel-react preset and all works with browserify, gulp and that stuff ... Do I miss some other component/setting?

Comment: It worked once i changed this: signup(evt) {
Probably because signup also recieves arguments .. i read something like that above arrows just now .. 
If you update your response with that change, I mark is as correct. Thanx a lot!

Comment: @Stefan updated but `= () =>` does work with parameters. I think it may be to do with how you define you component. I use this syntax: 
`class MyClass extends React.Component {
    signup = (evt) => {
    }
}`

And it works.

Comment: @Stefan If you are talking about the arguments object then you are correct, it will not work with that.